# Which is more performance friendly? If check inside function or before calling the function in Java

Tags: java, performance, logging

I want to use a if check before printing the log by checking the log level.
`logPacket` function is used couple of times. I'm confused whether should I check the log level before or after calling the `logPacket` function. Following code segments is what make me think about performance. Is it overengineering?

```
if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
    logPacket("Received Packet. ", packetCp, packet, Packet.Type.getTypeByValue(code).toString());
}
```

```
private void logPacket(String msg, ConnectPoint sessionInfo, Ethernet packet, String packetType) {
    if(log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log.info(msg + " type: {} to: {} client: {} stageCode: {} vlan: {} vlanPcp: {} srcMac: {} dstMac: {}", 
            packetType, sessionInfo, sessionInfo.port().name(), packet.getPriorityCode(), packet.getVlanID(), packet.getQinQVID(), packet.getSourceMAC(), packet.getDestinationMAC());
    }
}
```

Should I put the statement `log.isInfoEnabled()` inside the function before printing the log or should I use the if statement before calling the function as I indicated in the first place.

If log level is not info, then making extra call for the `logPacket` function degrades the performance I guess (not sure how much). But if I use the if check before the function call, code may get dirtier.

Which one looks more clean? I'm not sure.

Can't make a reasonable comparison.

Comment: "performance friendly?" -> the `if` statement will always be executed, no matter where it is, so that is no concern. If it is put before calling the method, the method will only be called if needed, so that is probably better for performance (ignoring eventual optimization potentials)

Comment: Use `if` first if any of the arguments to `logPacket` might have high evaluation cost - such as memory, file or db access, otherwise you're unlikely to see a difference if they are all simple get/member calls. For example what if typeByValue.toString was a huge memory size.

Answer (score 0):

Always measure different alternatives with realistic input, when you are worried about performance. Otherwise you cannot know if your change makes a noticable difference. Most of the time the performance impact negligible and you choose the best option for readability anyway.

A method call in Java is very cheap. It almost adds no overhead to call an additional method. Putting the `log.isInfoEnabled()` inside the `logPacket` method, makes the call cleaner and easier to read (one instead of 3 lines of code when calling and reducing an if-nesting every time it is called). Maybe rename the method to `infoLogPacket` to make the condition also clear from the method name.

However you should avoid to evaluate any values for the logging before checking the log level, as these would be wasted calls, if the log level is not active. `Packet.Type.getTypeByValue(code).toString()` should be called after `log.isInfoEnabled()` when you move the check into your method. So you have to change the method signature to pass the `code` instead of the `String` and do the convertion after the log level check.

So my solution would be:

```
private void infoLogPacket(String msg, ConnectPoint sessionInfo, Ethernet packet, Code code) {
    if(log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        String packetType = Packet.Type.getTypeByValue(code).toString();
        log.info(msg + " type: {} to: {} client: {} stageCode: {} vlan: {} vlanPcp: {} srcMac: {} dstMac: {}", 
            packetType, sessionInfo, sessionInfo.port().name(), packet.getPriorityCode(), packet.getVlanID(), packet.getQinQVID(), packet.getSourceMAC(), packet.getDestinationMAC());
    }
}
```